# Download Laravel is too slow using Composer

Tags: 14.04

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, My php version is 5.6.30. Composer version is 1.4.1.

I want to install Laravel but when I using composer (v1.4.1) to download Laravel with terminel:

```
sudo composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
```

it takes me 30 minutes to download it. 
I already read this solution but it's can help me for my solution. Everything is fine. I can download Laravel using composer but it's too slow.
Any suggestion for me ?
Thank guys.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue before, after a lot search i believe this was the best answer to fix composer slowness for me.

```
composer config --global repo.packagist composer https://packagist.org
```

by adding packagist repo globally so that composer can search for packages in packagist.